# Some of translated strings in django i18n are ignored

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have django app which uses i18n. Everything works fine except few string. Example:
I have form with code:

```
tos_accept = forms.BooleanField(label=u'%s <a href="/terms">%s</a>'%(_('I accept'),_('ToS')),error_messages={'required':_('Acceptance required')})
```

I have generated translation (using makemessages), then I have it translated. After all, I run the compilemessages command and restart sever. Unlucky, "`ToS`" and "`I accept`" are not being translated to other language. Could you tell me why?

Comment: did you import `_` as `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy`?

Comment: I have used ugettext_lazy

Comment: what happens if you change it to `ugettext`? Probably worth a try.

Comment: Do 'I accept' and 'ToS' have a `fuzzy`-tag in your `.po`-file?

Comment: I've checked it, there is no fuzzy-tag

Comment: Hmm I'm running out of ideas... what happens if you use named-string interpolation: `label=u'%(accept)s <a href="/terms">%(tos)s</a>') % {'accept': _('I accept'), 'tos': _('ToS')}`

Comment: Thank yout for your suggestion, but it didn't help :(